# I am having trouble with the Hangman program I made

Tags: python, pydev

I'm having trouble getting the correct output out of my code. I need it to provide the head, body, arms, legs one by one, but it won't. Please check my code.

```
import random
max_wrong = len(HANGMAN) -1
WORDS = ("Caleb","Owen","Ben","Adriane","Marley")
word = random.choice(WORDS)
so_far = "-" * len(word)
wrong = 0
used = []

while wrong < max_wrong and so_far != word:  #The start of the sequence  to make it loop
    print(HANGMAN[wrong])
    print("you used the following letters: ",used)
    print("So far the length of the word is ",so_far)

    guess = raw_input("What letter do you think is in the word? ")
    guess = guess.upper()

    while guess in used:
        print("Hey,wait a minute you have already guessed that word.")
        guess = raw_input("What letter do you think is in the word? ")
        guess = guess.upper()

used.append(guess)

if guess in used:
    print('Yes',guess,"is in the word")
    # new so_far
    new = " "
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if guess == word[i]:
            new += guess 

    else:
    new += so_far[i]
    max_wrong = len(HANGMAN) -1

    so_far = new

else:
    print("Sorry ", guess, " is not in the word")
    wrong += 1 

if wrong == max_wrong:
    print(HANGMAN[wrong])
    print"Oops sorry you have been hanged!"

else:
    print("You guessed it the word was ",word)
```

By the way I have already created the tuple with the "graphics" but stack overflow would not let me show it so I left it behind. It won't provide the body and it keeps saying that the letter is in the word. 
The output is this even though it is not in the word

```
 ------
 |    |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
----------

('you used the following letters: ', [])
('So far the length of the word is ', '-----')
What letter do you think is in the word? n
('Yes', 'N', 'is in the word')

 ------
 |    |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 ----------

('you used the following letters: ', ['N'])
('So far the length of the word is ', ' -----')
What letter do you think is in the word? k
('Yes', 'K', 'is in the word')

  ------
  |    |
  |
  |
  |
  |
  |
  |
  |
  ----------

 ('you used the following letters: ', ['N', 'K'])
 ('So far the length of the word is ', '  ----')
 What letter do you think is in the word?
```

Comment: How about giving some description as to what it is and is not doing.

Comment: You should add a question. And an example of what the output is and what you expect it to be.

Comment: Is the indentation in your code exactly as shown above?

Comment: Since the printout doesn't show the "Sorry" message, wrong obviously isn't getting incremented.  I don't see any words containing N and K - figure out why it thinks they are in the word.

Comment: FYI, according to the FAQ, this is the type of question that should be appropriate to StackOverflow - it asks about a specific programming problem, not general opinions or open-ended discussion.  However, one of the reasons it is getting voted down is that it is not re-usable - debugging your code isn't likely to help other programmers with their problems.  The FAQ probably should be updated to discuss questions of general interest vs. narrow interest.

Comment: I just wanna say thank you for the help. Is their a place however where a newb can get help when he needs it?

Comment: @Kbob1998 Look at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters, it looks like you have an undefined variable:

```
max_wrong = len(HANGMAN) -1
```

Do you mean that to be

```
max_wrong = len(word) -1
```

??  In that case you'd have to define it after you defined word.

You've also got to look at how you're setting up your loops... for example you've got an indented "else"  (not sure if this was just through your copy & paste).  And if you're trying to use

```
new = " "
```

to set up a blank string and add in letters each time they are correctly guessed you probably want that outside your if loop, otherwise it will overwrite a new blank string each time it runs through the loop.

Is this for your class homework?

Comment: Thank you,no I'm just interested in programming. I thought if i used max_wrong how i did it would go down the tuple every time I'm wrong.

Comment: what do you mean "it would go down the tuple"?

Answer (score 0):

Start with:

```
if guess in used: 
    print('Yes',guess,"is in the word")
```

Don't you want to check if guess is in word?